# Why can't I change the width of my turtle?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, python-turtle

I am making an app in Tkinter and turtle and I want to change the width of my turtle through number keypresses. So when I type in 2 it should change the user width to 2 and when I type 1 it should change the width to 1. However, when I press the number on my key it does not work?

Here is example code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import turtle
import time


# Screen
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(screen.winfo_screenwidth(), screen.winfo_screenheight()))
screen.title("Example Code")
screen.configure(bg="Gray")
# Canvas
canvas = Canvas(master=screen, width="666", height="666")
canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)


# Making The User
user = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
user.shape("triangle")
user.setheading(90)
user.speed(0)
user.color("black")
user.down()
user.goto(0, 0)
userspeed = 15
user.width(1)


# Width Functions
def width_one(event=None):
    user.width(1)


def width_two(event=None):
    user.width(2)

canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind('<1>', width_one)
canvas.bind('<2>', width_two)




screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are binding to clicks of mouse buttons 1 and 2, *not* keys.  Use `'1'` and `'2'` for the numeric keys.

Comment: I am trying to bind the number keys 1 & 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the problem seems to be with the functions, "*it doesn't make any change in the initial state"*, and also the key bindings are wrong `'<1>'` and `'<2>'`, wrong in the sense, it's not what you indent, as it refers to mouse button 1 and 2 and not the numeric keys 1 and 2. To bind it to the numeric key 1 and 2, it should be:

```
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind('1', width_one)
canvas.bind('2', width_two)
```

Since the function doesn't show any change in the initial stage, it won't make any change, to test it out, say:

```
# Completed Version
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind('1', lambda event:print('You pressed 1'))
canvas.bind('2', lambda event:print('You pressed 2'))
```

And you can notice 1 and 2 printed in the terminal when you press 1 and, respectively

Hope this cleared the issue, do let me know if any errors.

Cheers

Comment: @Skcoder im havent used turtle, so i dont know what your trying to do and why its wrong.

Comment: @Skcoder Actually the functions work, `width()` changes the width of the line right? Without any line drawn you can ensure it, when you move the arrow forward and the line extends, itll show the updated thickeness

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221477/discussion-between-skcoder-and-cool-cloud).

Comment: IDE
well its not that simple
i myself took up a project
and left it half way
cause the syntax marking and all is not easy
and module for it are not well documented
but as a base code
you would use tkinter `Text` widget and `exec()` to execute the codes written in it. After all python IDLE is made from tkinter, i believe